# How can I set QGroupBox's title with HTML expressions? (Python)

Tags: python, html, qt, groupbox

I want to set my `QGroupBox`'s title **with HTML expressions** in python program,

e.g. :
 A<sub>BC</sub>. (subscript)

Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QGroupBox`'s `title` property does not support HTML. The only customization you can do through the `title` string (besides the text itself) is the addition of an ampersand (`&`) for keyboard accelerators.

In short, unlike `QLabel`, you can't use HTML with `QGroupBox`.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if you feel it is correct. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works for me :

```
QLabel *labelHTML = new QLabel("<strong>Hello</strong> " "<font color=red>World!");
```

This displays :

[image]

Comment: thanks for your editing my question. but, sorry for confusing you. i mean, i already know about QLabel but i don't know how to set QGroupBox's title with HTML expressions like QLabel.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want just to change a style, you can call `setStyleSheet()` method for your `QGroupBox` (see code below) or use @IAmInPLS's `QLabel` example.

```
box->setStyleSheet("QGroupBox { color: red; } ");
```

Comment: Thanks. but i just want HTML expressions.